# formatted string input and error in C

Tags: c

```
struct account {
  float interestRate;
  char accountType[21];
};

void writeAccounts() {
  struct account Acc;
  FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt", "a");

  printf("New interestRate : ");
  scanf("%f", &Acc.interestRate);
  printf("New  accountType : ");
  scanf("%*c%20[^\n]", Acc.accountType);

  fprintf(fp, "%.2f %s\n", Acc.interestRate, Acc.accountType);

  fclose(fp);
}

int main() {
  int select = 0;

  do {
    scanf("%d", &select);
    switch (select) {
      case 1:
        displayAccounts();
        break;
      case 2:
        getRecNo();
        break;
      case 3:
        writeAccounts();
        break;
    }
  } while (select != 0);

  return 0
```

Above is my code(deleted some unrelated functions) in C.
When I try to type a string more than 20 characters for the accountType in "writeAccounts" function, program starts to skip few steps until it saves all the characters I have input.
(CANNOT USE FGETS!! my prof doesnt allow to :/)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cY0K4.jpg

1. why is this happening?
2. isn't %20[^\n] means its only going to accept 20 characters even if user puts more?
3. possible way to prevent this ?

Comment: "CANNOT USE FGETS" - why not? And is this supposed to be C or C++?

Comment: edited to only contain C // since my class havent covered fgets in the lecture we are not allowed to use fgets for some reason....

Comment: Look up the required syntax and semantics for the`*` modifier.

Comment: @ChewChew great professor anyway. And what if someone is a passionate programmer and knows C better than him. He wants to get in troubles one day

Comment: The `%*c` would be better replaced by a space.  And do test the return value of `scanf()` every time — make sure it returns 1 (it might return 0 or EOF instead, but you check that you got what you wanted).  And not being allowed to use standard functions simply because they've not been taught in class is … moderately silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. why is this happening?

The excess input remains in the input buffer and is read by subsequent `scanf` calls.

> 2. isn't %20[^\n] means its only going to accept 20 characters even if user puts more?

That is correct, and as mentioned any remaining input is not processed.

> 3. possible way to prevent this ?

After a successful scan (20 characters or less) the newline remains in the input buffer. You can do various things.

Firstly you could check if the next input character ***is*** the expected newline:

```
if (getchar() != '\n') {
    // add code here to report the error and take evasive action
}
```

Or you could simply truncate and ignore any excess input by cleaning off the buffer:

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
    // eats up the input buffer, the code is in the loop control
}
```